# Plotly R subplot by group produces error (identical code to example)

Tags: r, plotly

I am literally copying and pasting this code from the plotly R examples page and it produces an error. Can't seem to get this to work.

```
iris$id <- as.integer(iris$Species)
p <- plot_ly(iris, x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width,
             group = Species,
             xaxis = paste0('x', id), mode = 'markers')
p <- subplot(p)
Error in locator(2) : plot.new has not been called yet
p
Warning message:
In par(old.par) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot
```

Here is the package version I am using:

```
packageVersion('plotly')
[1] ‘3.4.13’
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: works with plotly_3.4.3  ggplot2_2.1.0

Comment: I am using dev version from Github because there is a bug in subplot fixed in that version and not CRAN version. Latest on CRAN is 3.4.1 I think. Any way I can downgrade to 3.4.3 with install from github? Never tried that.

Comment: it is also a dev version I am using but older than yours :-)

Comment: Right....Tried on another machine where I have 3.4.9 dev one installed, and that seems to work too. Something must be broken in most recent dev version. Just filed a issue report on Github. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure `htmlwidgets` is up to date, too; that's caused issues for me before in packages that depend on it.

Comment: It is at version 0.6. That is the latest on CRAN.

Comment: strange, working for me with newest htmlwidgets (github) and newest plotly (github 3.4.13).  can you add full `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()`?

Comment: Upon further inspection, the plotly::subplot() was getting overriden by Hmisc::subplot(), a package I was using in my code for cut2(). Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Works on my version, I'm on the github dev version judging by the `.9000` but in any case I believe the last plot_ly updates uses `dplyr` and the piping system.

```
packageVersion('plotly')
> '4.5.6.9000'

iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    do(p = plot_ly(., x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, name = ~Species)) %>%
    subplot()
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR]